# How to wait on the for each function in js

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make api call and store the results in array. function itself is an async. Here's a code.

```
async function setPoliciesData(policies) {
    let tmpPolicies = {};
    await policies.forEach((policy) => {
      const tmp = { ...policy };
      // Here I need help. This returns promise Instade remembers How to wait till promise finishes
      tmp["Name"] = getPolicyNameFromLocalStrage(policy.id);
      try {
        if (policy?.audience?.id) {
          tmp["members"] = getMembersFromAudienceId(policy.audience.id);
        } else {
          tmp["members"] = [];
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }

      let id = policy.id;
      console.log("Setting policy ID : " + policy.id);
      tmpPolicies[policy.id] = tmp;
    });
    console.log("Done the processing");
    return tmpPolicies;
  }
```

I am getting Promise object in return. I would want members returnd array.

I tried to console log and I am seeing that issue seems to be because of method is not async. What is proper way to fix it.

Comment: `await policies.forEach` makes no sense. [`forEach`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) returns nothing.  Consider using [`map`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with [`Promise.all`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) instead. Are `getPolicyNameFromLocalStrage` and `getMembersFromAudienceId` asynchronous? Then _these_ function calls must be `await`-ed. _“I am getting Promise object in return”_ — Yes, that’s a key feature of an `async` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I refactored some of your code, but if you should make the function inside of the forEach asynchronous. In this case, I changed it to `map` to be a bit easier to follow. The key at the end is to `return Promise.all()` which will wait for all of the inner promises to be resolved before returning:

```
async function setPoliciesData(policies) {
  const tmpPolicies = policies.map(async (policy) => {
    policy.Name = await getPolicyNameFromLocalStrage(policy.id);
    
    try {
      policy.members = policy.audience && policy.audience.id 
        ? await getMembersFromAudienceId(policy.audience.id) 
        : [];
    } catch (e) {
      console.error('Error: ' + e);
    }

    return policy;
  });
  
  console.log("Done the processing");
  return Promise.all(tmpPolicies);
}
```